# How to assign a value to a new column with a string condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to assign values to a new column in the data-frame based on condition, if the first column contains a certain letter or not. f the first column only contains one letter, I use the dummy variable function. But how about, if the first column contains numbers, strings, and Nan?

Here is a example:

```py
# Before
   c1
0   a
1   2
2   b
3   c
4   ab
5   bc
6   NaN

#After
    c1  a   b   c
0   a   1   0   0
1   2   0   0   0
2   b   0   1   0
3   c   0   0   1
4   ab  1   1   0
5   bc  0   1   1
6   NaN 0   0   0
```

I try  `str.contains()` to assign, but I get an error:

```py
x['a'] = 1 if x.c1.str.contains('a') else 0

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do something like this:

```
df['a'] = df['c1'].str.contains('a').astype(int)
```

... but this raises a `ValueError` if you have any `NaN` values in `df['c1']` (as you do in your example).

Here's an alternative using `df.apply`:

```
df['a'] = df['c1'].apply(lambda x: int('a' in x) if isinstance(x, str) else 0)
```

This approach also deals with columns that are composed of multiple types: it returns 1 only when a given row is a string, in addition to having the appropriate character inside.

Comment: @Carlos thank you comments are unneeded, if the answer is helpful you should upvote and/or accept it as a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

For your problem you can use the pandas.get_dummies() [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), which convert a categorical variable into indicators

1. Convert your dataframe to a list then (Optional)
2. Then create classifcation dummy variables with this code:

```
    lst = ['a', 2, 'b', 'c', 'ab', np.nan]

    pd.get_dummies(lst).T
```

3. Compare and merge the dummy-identifier for your desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways one of your main problems is that your column is not an string, you can do it like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{"c1": "a"}, {"c1":2}])
df["new_column"] = 0
df["new_column"][df["c1"].astype(str).str.contains('a')] = 1
```

or

```py
def custom_funct(row):
    print(row)
    if "a" in str(row["c1"]):
        row["new_column"] = 1
    else:
        row["new_column"] = 0
    return row


df = pd.DataFrame([{"c1": "a"}, {"c1":2}])
df["new_column"] = None
df = df.apply(custom_funct,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df
    c1
0   a
1   2
2   b
3   c
4   ab
5   bc
6   NaN
```

Firstly, you can replace `NaN`s with some dummy character (say #) as it will be easier to handle strings. Then you can `apply` `list` to the whole column such that you get each of the characters separately. Thereafter, you can use `explode` to get the each of the character in each row separted to multiple rows. Convert to dataframe and add a column of ones such that a pivot table can be created.

```
temp = df['c1'].fillna('#').apply(list).explode().to_frame().reset_index()
temp['vals'] = 1
temp
  index c1  vals
0   0   a   1
1   1   2   1
2   2   b   1
3   3   c   1
4   4   a   1
5   4   b   1
6   5   b   1
7   5   c   1
8   6   #   1
```

Then you can create the `pivot_table` with `c1` as columns and the column with 1s as the values. After that you can just retain the columns  which are alphabets. Finally, concat the `temp` table with original df.

```
temp = pd.pivot_table(temp, columns='c1', index="index", values='vals')
cols_retain = [c for c in temp.columns if re.search(r'[A-Za-z]', c)]
pd.concat([df, temp[cols_retain].fillna(0)], axis=1)
    c1  a   b   c
0   a   1.0 0.0 0.0
1   2   0.0 0.0 0.0
2   b   0.0 1.0 0.0
3   c   0.0 0.0 1.0
4   ab  1.0 1.0 0.0
5   bc  0.0 1.0 1.0
6   NaN 0.0 0.0 0.0
```